# The [Salesforce] ecosystem

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

While hunting for my next zombie to take down, I encountered the following question: 
[Patient Appointment CSV to insert records using simple_salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197068/patient-appointment-csv-to-insert-records-using-simple-salesforce)

A question that seemed well written, almost complete, except this part:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
```

Those are not user-defined functions.

Turns out there's a Python REST API for Salesforce called [`simple-salesforce`](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/). Knowing we've had Salesforce questions before I thought I'd put a tag on it, but this is where it gets complicated.

[Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/products/what-is-salesforce/) is a CRM platform. [Salesforce-Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm) is a programming language "that allows developers to execute flow and transaction control statements on Salesforce servers in conjunction with calls to the API". Apparently there are also a bunch of APIs in other languages that can talk to Salesforce as well, one of them being the `simple-salesforce` in the Code Review question.

A platform, a language and a (bunch of) API(s) all under one tag.

[force.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force.com), [salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce) [apex-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex-code) and [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex) are synonyms. With [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex) as parent. And that's unfortunate, since now I can't put a Salesforce-related tag on the question while it would definitely benefit from one.

I don't think [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex) is the correct parent tag. We will get more questions like this and we haven't even talked about the [Salesforce lightning framework app-builder](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/lightning/) yet, which may or may not be the new name for [force.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force.com).

I'm looking for solutions to this (potential) mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(**Note**: Mast and I [discussed this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55011675#55011675) this is a complete write up of my POV from this)

## Salesforce

### Salesforce's Developer Tools

I think that Salesforce has three major sections to their developer tools.

1. A language - Apex <sup>[[W]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce#Apex) [[S]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm)</sup>
2. REST APIs <sup>[[S]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/)</sup>

   - [B2C Commerce Developer Sandbox API's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sfcc-ccdx)
   - [Einstein Prediction Service Scoring API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/einstein-predict)
   - [Einstein Vision and Einstein Language](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/einstein-vision-language)
   - [Marketing Cloud REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sfmc)
   - [Salesforce IoT API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/iot)
3. A component framework - Lightning <sup>[[W]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce#Lightning) [[S]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm)</sup>

   - Models:

     - [Lightning Web Components model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc)
     - [Aura Components model](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_components.htm)
   - Builtin [components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)

### Tagging Decisions

I do not think we should crate subtags for things like the IoT API, Aura components, etc at this time.

1. We do not have a lot of Salesforce questions.
2. The names I'd suggest on these tags can cause problems later on.
3. I think by creating 9+ tags at once we'd be setting ourselves up for problems later on as I'm bound to make a mistake somewhere.

   **Example**: there is reference to an Apex REST API but I can't find a link that explains it.

**Note**: This **does not** mean that we *cannot* have these tags in the future. I am just suggesting we hold off this discussion for another day.

### Tag Proposal

- [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex)
  Synonyms: [apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex), [apex-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex-code), [force.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force.com)
- [salesforce-lightning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-lightning)
  Synonyms: [lightning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning), [salesforce-components](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-components)
- [salesforce-rest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-rest)
  Synonyms: [salesforce-apex-rest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex-rest)
- Blacklist: [salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce)

## Generic 3rd Party Interfaces to Other APIs

For languages that are not Apex they will most likely use a library to interact with the REST APIs.
The generic situation is "I am using a {library} to interface with {API} in {language}".
For example "I am using [simple_salesforce](https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/) to interface with Salesforce {name} REST API in Python".

At first I'd like to have kept the amount of tags to a minimum. However after short analysis I've decided that it's fine to have tags for language specific libraries.

- "Only tag with {library} and {language}"
  If someone knowns {API} they'd need to follow lots of tags.
- "Only tag with {API} and {language}"
  The situation will become complicated and annoying if the ecosystem grows to the point that the libraries are vastly different than the APIs.

And so I suggest tagging with all three tags. Such as [simple-salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple-salesforce)[salesforce-rest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-rest)[python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).

## Example Tagging

- [Refactoring APEX to keep all database calls outside of for loops](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/121032)
  [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex)
- [Design pattern for logger implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/237566)
  [salesforce-apex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-apex)[object-oriented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)[design-patterns](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns)
- [Patient Appointment CSV to insert records using simple_salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/197068)
  [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python)[python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)[salesforce-rest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-rest)[simple-salesforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple-salesforce)
- [TypeScript Salesforce client library wrapper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/229514)
  [typescript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typescript)[object-oriented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented)[wrapper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wrapper)[salesforce-rest](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salesforce-rest)[jsforce](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsforce)